# Full Page Section CSS

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass

Im working on my very first website/freelance project. I have some knowledge of html/css ruby rails and bootstrap so far.

I was wondering if you could help me out with something I havn't been able to look up. I have tried to find out how to make certain part of the page take up the entire portion of the browser's window. The site I am working on is 1 long page, with 4 different sections, each of which needs to take the entire browser's view. I was wondering if there was an easy way with bootstrap to do this? Any help is appreciated, thanks so much.

Comment: Could you provide a little more detail plus any code you already have? For example each section filling the screen are they vertically stacked and get displayed as you scroll down?

Comment: Block level elements take up the entire width of their parent element by default.  The logical solution is to not use Bootstrap's classes that restrict the width of the element.

Comment: So i have 2 rows on a bootstrap page, and they just stop there on my 24 inch monitor. One row has a whit background, and the 2nd has a black background. Underneath that, its just white space.

Answer (score 0):

Use the fluid grid (http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#fluidGridSystem) and add 100% width to your container divs, like:

css:

```
    <style type="text/css">
    /* after your bootstrap css inclusing */    
    .container, .navbar-static-top .container, .navbar-fixed-top .container, .navbar-fixed-bottom .container 
    {
    width: 100%;
    }

    </style>
```

html:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="span4" style="background-color:red;">...</div>
  <div class="span8" style="background-color:yellow;">...</div>
</div> 
</div>
```

**update**:
Split in rows of 50% height:

css:

```
    <style type="text/css">
    /* after your bootstrap css inclusing */    
    body, html, .container,.row-fluid .hunderd{ height:100%; min-height:100%; !important;}
    .container, .navbar-static-top .container, .navbar-fixed-top .container, .navbar-fixed-bottom .container 
    {
    width: 100%;
    }
    .fifty {height:50%;min-height:50%;}
    </style>
```

html:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row-fluid fifty">
  <div class="span6 hunderd" style="background-color:red;">...</div>
  <div class="span6 hunderd" style="background-color:yellow;">...</div>
</div> 
<div class="row-fluid fifty">
  <div class="span6 hunderd" style="background-color:blue;">...</div>
  <div class="span6 hunderd" style="background-color:orange;">...</div>
</div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Im able to have my width 100%, but my heights need to take up 50+50% of the page. Its just 1 page with 2 sections that i placed into rows.